# Updating Item media field with specific media Sitecore powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions, sitecore-api

I have 400 product items. Previously, we have a common thumbnail image for all products. Now, I added a new image field (thumbnail image), all products I need to assign a common specific thumbnail image.

I wrote PowerShell script but it's not working

```
$thumbnailImage = Get-Item -Path 'master:\sitecore\media library\xyz\pqr\mno\infotumbnail410PD1'

$itemPath= Get-Item -Path 'master:\sitecore\content\sites\abc'

$itemPath.Editing.BeginEdit()

[Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField]$fieldValueLink = $itemPath["Product Image"]
$fieldValueLink= $thumbnailImage 

$itemPath.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Please suggest me on the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In theory you should just be able to do this:

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\sitecore\content\sites\abc"
$item.Image = Get-Item -Path "master:\sitecore\media library\xyz\pqr\mno\infotumbnail410PD1"
```

from this page: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items

But I couldn't figure out how to do that with fields with a space in them. So I did it like so instead but I think this is a bit hacky as I've created the field value with a string.format which is not very nice.

```
$thumbnailImage = Get-Item -Path 'master:\sitecore\media library\xyz\pqr\mno\infotumbnail410PD1'

$item= Get-Item -Path 'master:\sitecore\content\sites\abc'

$item.Editing.BeginEdit()

$item.Fields["Listing Image"].Value = [string]::Format("<image mediaid='{0}' />",$thumbnailImage.ID)

$item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

There must be a better way of doing this though.

Comment: Thank you @Adam

Answer (score 0):

When testing your script, I was having an error with the cast of ImageField and also saw that in RAW values, it was adding the value `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`. I did a modification of your script and tested it. Please use the below script. You may need to update it to fit your requirements

```
$thumbnailImage = Get-Item -Path 'master:\sitecore\media library\xyz\pqr\mno\infotumbnail410PD1'

$itemPath= Get-Item -Path 'master:\sitecore\content\sites\abc'


$itemPath.Editing.BeginEdit()

$itemPath."Product Image" = $thumbnailImage

$itemPath.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

$mid = fetching media item id from media library

```
$m.Editing.BeginEdit()
  $t='<file mediaid="'+ $mid +'" src=' + '"-/media/'+$mGuid+'.ashx" />';
  $m["ProductListing"]= $t
 $m.Editing.EndEdit();
```